# Xcode5 and iOS7: trailing whitespaces in strings in Localizable.strings not working anymore

Tags: string, whitespace, ios7, xcode5, trailing

In my **Localizable.strings** I define a string with trailing whitespaces like this:

```
"%@ points  " = "%@ Punkte  ";
```

This worked just fine in iOS6 but when runing on an iOS7 emulator, the string is trimmed and the trailing whitespaces are stripped off.

Background: The string above is right-aligned in a label. I use the whitespaces as a padding since I dont want to subclass UILabel or write a bunch of code for just one label.

I also tried using ASCII signs, but this also did not work.

Any suggestions for a simple soultion would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps you can try this workaround with NSMutableAttributedString which worked for me. The "." is put in place of the whitespace.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.", count]];


 [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,string.length-1)];

 [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor clearColor] range:NSMakeRange(string.length-1,1)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [non breaking space character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)?

Comment: Yes, I tried 0x00A0. It works when the last char is NOT an empty char: `"%@ points%C." = "%@ Punkte%C.";` Where %C is where I add the 0x00A0. But when I add it as the last character its been removed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am solving this issue by adding the label as a subview to a view and setting the width of the label  a bit smaller that that of the view.

All styling, i.e. background image, animations etc. is done to the view, not the label. Not the KISS principle but it works.

Thanks anyway.