# UILabel text include multiple spaces at the end

Tags: objective-c, text, uilabel, string-formatting

In Objective-C I have a UILabel that says 'Loading'. Every 0.5 seconds the string will gain another '.' until there are 3 dots, then it starts over. The problem I'm facing is that my string is centered and when each dot appears, the string jumps. The reason the string jumps is because the UILabel keeps trimming the right whitespace.

Here is an example of whats currently happening.

```
+------------+
|  Loading   |
+------------+
|  Loading.  |
+------------+
| Loading..  |
+------------+
| Loading... |
+------------+
```

And this is what I want to happen.

```
+------------+
| Loading    |
+------------+
| Loading.   |
+------------+
| Loading..  |
+------------+
| Loading... |
+------------+
```

Telling the UILabel to have a greater width and be left aligned is not an option. This needs to be done with the text.

I found this [link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html), but I still cant figure it out.

What I currently have is this.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%-3.3s", [@"" UTF8String]];
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%-3.3s", [@"." UTF8String]];
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%-3.3s", [@".." UTF8String]];
@"...";
```

Comment: why is left aligned ***not*** an option?  it seems like the easiest solution.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann because the view that the UILabel is in, is extremely dynamic and used in many places. Extending its already enormous amount of functionality is not desirable.

Comment: Are you using a monospaced font in that label? If not then adding spaces is unlikely to give you aligned text anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way text works on label is - it is formatted by standard formatting information - like trimming etc. If you don't want ios to take control on that. You can programmatically set *attributedText*. this does not go thru formatting. Here is apple's documentation on that

> attributedText The styled text displayed by the label.
>
> @property(nonatomic,copy) NSAttributedString *attributedText
>   Discussion This property is nil by default. Assigning a new value to
>   this property also replaces the value of the text property with the
>   same string data, albeit without any formatting information. In
>   addition, assigning a new a value updates the values in the font,
>   textColor, and other style-related properties so that they reflect the
>   style information starting at location 0 in the attributed string.

Essentially set uilabel's attributedtext to "Loading  "

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914838/xcode5-and-ios7-trailing-whitespaces-in-strings-in-localizable-strings-not-work/18973294#18973294)

the solution is add trailing visible charaters and set them transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Set `label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentNatural`. Since ios 9, this is default, before that it used to be NSTextAlignmentLeft.

Now since your text has to be centred, wrap it in a UIView with all the margins of the label anchored with that of the wrapper view. Then center the wrapper instead of label.

Here's the code:

```
UIView* wrapper = [[UIView alloc] init];
wrapper.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
//This sets the wrapper at the center of where you were adding the label previously
[wrapper.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: superview.centerXAnchor].active = YES;

label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[label.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:wrapper.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
[label.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:wrapper.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
[label.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:wrapper.topAnchor].active = YES;
[label.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:wrapper.bottomAnchor].active = YES;

label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentNatural
...
```