# How do I add trailing whitespace to an NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uilabel

In Xcode 6, I'm trying to assign the `text` property of a `UILabel` to a string of text. Generally, that's a  rather mundane task, but the `UILabel` is right-aligned in a cursive font, that is sometimes partially cut off. In order to fix this, I want to add a couple spaces worth of whitespace to the end of a string, before assigning the `UILabel`'s `text` property to said string. What I'm trying to do now looks like this:

```
self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"- %@  ", words];
```

Unfortunately, the whitespace at the end is being trimmed automatically, and I can't figure out how to get it to stop doing that. I've attempted the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386351/objective-c-code-to-right-pad-a-nsstring) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914838/xcode5-and-ios7-trailing-whitespaces-in-strings-in-localizable-strings-not-work), with the latter actually causing a crash. Could anyone please tell me how to create an `NSString` and leave the trailing whitespace?

Comment: tried UILable's NSLineBreakMode?  @property(nonatomic)        NSLineBreakMode    lineBreakMode;   // default is NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail. used for single and multiple lines of text